# Need to this table with 100 rows and assign a valor to the code PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I need to solve this simple thing:
Got this code:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("d2ladder.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
?>    
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" align="center" style="text-align:center">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="<?php if ($xml->ladder[12]->char[0]->status == "alive") { echo "alive"; } else { echo "dead"; } ?>">
      <td width="10%">1.</td>
      <td width="50%" style="text-align:left"><?php echo $xml->ladder[12]->char[0]->prefix; ?> <?php echo $xml->ladder[12]->char[0]->name; ?></td>
      <td width="10%"><?php echo $xml->ladder[12]->char[0]->class; ?></td>
      <td width="10%"><?php echo $xml->ladder[12]->char[0]->level; ?></td>
      <td width="20%"><?php echo $xml->ladder[12]->char[0]->experience; ?></td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="<?php if ($xml->ladder[12]->char[1]->status == "alive") { echo "alive"; } else { echo "dead"; } ?>">
      <td width="10%">2.</td>
      <td width="50%" style="text-align:left"><?php echo $xml->ladder[12]->char[1]->prefix; ?> <?php echo $xml->ladder[12]->char[1]->name; ?></td>
      <td width="10%"><?php echo $xml->ladder[12]->char[1]->class; ?></td>
      <td width="10%"><?php echo $xml->ladder[12]->char[1]->level; ?></td>
      <td width="20%"><?php echo $xml->ladder[12]->char[1]->experience; ?></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Need to create rows on this table till char[99]
Maybe I need to use while? Because sometimes it wont get to 99 on the sitemap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use for/while cycle:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    ?>
  <tr class="<?php if ($xml->ladder[12]->char[$i]->status == "alive") { echo "alive"; } else { echo "dead"; } ?>">
  <td width="10%"><?php echo $i; ?>.</td>
  <td width="50%" style="text-align:left"><?php echo $xml->ladder[12]->char[$i]->prefix; ?> <?php echo $xml->ladder[12]->char[$i]->name; ?></td>
  <td width="10%"><?php echo $xml->ladder[12]->char[$i]->class; ?></td>
  <td width="10%"><?php echo $xml->ladder[12]->char[$i]->level; ?></td>
  <td width="20%"><?php echo $xml->ladder[12]->char[$i]->experience; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php }
```

See [for cycle](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice! Works, now I need to it check how many entries.. because it will random, sometimes I'll have 10 and other 100 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Users\Fabio\Documents\9-SITES\d2evo\ladder.php on line 11

Comment: Try using $i < sizeof($xml->$ladder[12]->char)

Comment: Works!! Just a typo $i < sizeof($xml->$ladder[12]->char) the ladder dont have the $, correct: $i < sizeof($xml->ladder[12]->char)